# How do I unit test $scope.broadcast, $scope.$on using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm newbie to AngularJs/NodeJs world, so forgive if this is a basic question to some.

So in a nutshell I've two controllers, the first controller `$broadcast` an 'Id'  and the second controller fetches that Id with `$on` and then passes that Id to an intermediate `service`, which makes an `$http` ajax call and returns a single `Book` object.

How do I unit test $scope.broadcast, $scope.$on using Jasmine

### firstCtrl

```
.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, ...){
    $scope.selectGridRow = function() {
        if($scope.selectedRows[0].total !=0)
            $scope.$broadcast('id', $scope.selectedRows[0].id);//Just single plain ID
    };
});
```

### secondCtrl

```
.controller('secondCtrl',
    function($scope, bookService) {
        $scope.$on('id', function(event, id) {
            bookService.getBookDetail(id).then(function(d) {
                $scope.book = d.book;
            });
        });
    });
```

### expected Json obj

```
var arr = "book" : [ {
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "Tomcat",
            "edition" : "9.1"
           }
          ]
```

Let me know if anyone wants me to post the `$http` service that's used by the second controller.

### expected behavior

So from the top of my head, ideally, I would like to test every possible scenario, but something like below, which can then expend:

```
expect(scope.book).toEqual(arr);
expect(scope.book).not.toEqual(undefined);
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you please describe what you expect from the test to do?

Comment: @DavidBohunek - Just added that to the question

Answer (score 1):

First you should do the broadcast on `$rootScope` then you can receive on `$scope`.
Now to the testing. I assume you want to include real request to your API via `bookService` and `$http`. This can be mocked but I'll focus on the real call. Let me know if you need the mocked one.

Before the actual test, you will need to do some injections/instantiations:

- Initialize your app
- Inject `$controller`, `$rootScope`, `$httpBackend` and `bookService`
- Create scopes for firstController and SecondController and store it in a variable
- Store `bookService` and `$httpBackend` in variables
- Instantiate the controllers and store them

Then in the actual test you must tell `$httpBackend` what to do when it caches request for the books (or books). Construct `$httpBackend.whenGET("/api/books/1").passThrough();` will pass request with url `"/api/books/1"` to the server. 
Next your must setup property `selectedRows` on `firstScope` so it fulfills the condition in function `selectGridRow` in your `firstCtrl`.

Now you can call function `selectGridRow` to trigger the broadcast and API call. But you must wrap it in `runs` function so Jasmine recognizes this as an async call and will wait for it to finish. The 'waiting' is defined in `waitsFor` call. It will wait until it gets a book and it waits max 5000 ms then the test will be marked as failed.

Last step is to check expected result. We don't have to check for `undefined` anymore as the test would not get to here anyway. The check must be wrapped again `runs` call so it is executed afters successful 'waitsFor'.

Here is the full code:

```
describe("Broadcast between controllers", function () {

    beforeEach(module('app')); //app initialization

    var firstScope;
    var secondScope;

    var bookService;
    var $httpBackend;

    var firstController;
    var secondController;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _bookService_, _$httpBackend_) {
        firstScope = $rootScope.$new();
        secondScope = $rootScope.$new();

        bookService = _bookService_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        firstController = $controller('firstCtrl', { $scope: firstScope });
        secondController = $controller('secondCtrl', { $scope: firstScope, bookService: bookService });
    }));


    it("should work", function () {

        $httpBackend.whenGET("/api/books/1").passThrough();

        firstScope.selectedRows = [{ id: 1, total: 1000 }];
        secondScope.book = null;

        runs(function () {
            firstScope.selectGridRow();
        });

        waitsFor(function () {
            return secondScope.book != null;
        }, "Data not received in expected time", 5000);

        runs(function () {
            expect(secondScope.book[0].id).toEqual(1);
        });
    });

});
```